# Fluid Dynamics: describing difference in behaviour of a particle released from the origin into flow

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

I've been given a flow field $$\mathbf{u} = (\cos(\omega t), x\sin(\omega t), 0)$$ and have found the streamlines and path lines etc. However I am stuck on trying to figure out what the difference in behaviour of a particle released at the origin would be if this was instead $$\mathbf{u} = (\cos(\omega t), x\sin(\sigma t), 0)$$ with $\sigma \neq \omega$
I've tried trying to find the path lines of this but it got complicated and I'm after an intuitive description of what actually would happen to the particle. Any help appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure the scenario in the second case is physically possible. How can the *coordinates* of the same point be out of phase? SMH! The first case, you have particles moving in an elliptical path about the origin. The second case I can't fathom.

Comment: What do you mean by out of phase? Plotting the path lines for the original case I've got a vertical oscillation about the y axis, I just can't work out how this would change if omega was replaced by a different constant in the y component of the flow field.

Comment: Sorry, I meant they have different frequencies of oscillation -- but my point is how could that possibly be? How could the coordinates vary at different rates when they're supposed to work in synchrony, being *co*ordinates?

Comment: They still work together in the sense they both vary with time and the y velocity depends on the x velocity, but the periods are different, so say omega was 2 and sigma was 3, what difference does this make physically as opposed to both being 2? I'm wondering if I need to think casewise, so what if omega is larger vs what if sigma is larger etc

Comment: I don't see anything relating the coordinates, except $x$ here doesn't denote a constant, as I've hitherto assumed, but the first coordinate, so that we have $y=x\sin \omega t.$ Is this indeed the case?

Comment: Yes that is the case

Answer (score 0):

So you have to solve the system $$\dot{x} = \cos(\omega t), \quad \dot{y} = x\sin(\sigma t),\quad \dot{z} = 0.$$Taking the easy things out of the way first, we get $$x = \frac{1}{\omega}\sin(\omega t),\quad z= 0,$$as the particle is released from the origin. So we plug that expression for $x$ and get $$\dot{y} = \frac{1}{\omega}\sin(\omega t)\cos(\sigma t).$$But we can join them [using a product-to-sum formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formulae), and get $$\dot{y} = \frac{1}{2\omega}(\cos((\omega-\sigma)t)-\cos((\omega+\sigma)t)).$$Then it follows that $$y = \frac{1}{2\omega(\omega-\sigma)}\sin((\omega-\sigma)t) - \frac{1}{2\omega(\omega+\sigma)}\sin((\omega+\sigma)t).$$Then you can proceed with the analysis using these formulas. I'm not sure if there's some immediate intuition to be drawn from this solution (at least I can't see it right now myself).

Comment: This is as far as I got but it's just not obvious to me what the main difference would be! It's a past exam question I'm trying and only a couple of marks so seems like it should be a straightforward conclusion